# Option spreads in registered accounts

Tags: discussion

Why [Option spreads in registered accounts](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/44149/10763) closed? This isn't my question.

I want answer it with https://www.interactivebrokers.ca/en/index.php?f=13406&p=tfsa

[RSP and TFSA Information | Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.ca/en/index.php?f=13406&p=tfsa)

> TFSA is allowed to trade the following qualified investments:
>
> - Stocks listed on designated US and Canadian exchanges (excluding Venture-NEX segment and CSE single listed stocks)
> - Long equity call options
> - Long equity put options
> - Short equity call options with a fully covered position (covered call)
> - Long equity put options with a fully covered position (protective put).
> - Long put/call options on indices.
> - Warrants/Rights if the underlying asset acquired under the right to purchase is a qualified investment.
> - U.S. Bonds.
> - FX conversions limited to USD/CAD

Answer (score 2):

The question asks *"Are there any option brokers [...]"*.

That kind of question is a request for a product/service recommendation and so was eventually closed as off-topic. Please refer to [what topics you can ask about](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Notice specifically:

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> [...]
>
> - Requests for specific service provider recommendations; e.g. asking where to get a loan, what broker to use, etc.